# Derivative of a function from $M(n\times n) \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: matrices, derivatives

Given is the function $f_{i,j}: M(n\times n) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as the $(i,j)$-th element of $X^2$. Give the differential and the derivative of $f$.

I don't have a clue where to start, since I cannot seem to workout a way to write the function as a formula. Could anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are considering is
$$
f_{i,j}:M\longmapsto \sum_{k=1}^n m_{i,k}m_{k,j}.
$$

Each term is obtained by composition of the linear map $M\longmapsto (M,M)$ followed by the bilinear map $(M,N)\longmapsto M_{i,k}N_{k,j}$.

The differential of the first one if $H\longmapsto (H,H)$ at every $M$ since it is linear.
And the differential of the second one is $(H,K)\longmapsto h_{i,k}n_{k,j}+m_{i,k}h_{k,j}$ at $(M,N)$, by bilinearity.

So the differential is
$$
df_{i,j}(M)(H)=\sum_{k=1}^nh_{i,k}m_{k,j}+m_{i,k}h_{k,j}=(HM+MH)_{i,j}.
$$

An alternative is to say is the composition of $M\longmapsto M^2$ with the linear form $M\longmapsto m_{i,j}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $A=(a_{ij})\in M(n\times n)$

Then $f_{i,j}(A)=\sum_k^na_{ik}a_{kj}$